# How to transfer data between 2 phones using Bluetooth and React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

my question is: Is it possible to transfer data between 2 phones using Bluetooth and React native?

For the past couple of days I have been researching React Native and the bluetooth protocol. And I have been able to make a simple BLE scanner in React Native. After accomplishing this I wanted to link my two phones together via bluetooth but my scanner did not see my other phone. This is where I learned the difference between Bluetooth Classic and BLE.

What I want to accomplish is to create an app which can sent small chunks of data to another phone via Bluetooth. Is this possible? Can I use BLE for this? Or do I need Bluetooth Classic?

And if I need Bluetooth Classic does anybody have code snippets, or libraries to help me? I did find this repository: https://github.com/kenjdavidson/react-native-bluetooth-classic
But I did not understand how to install/use it.

My simple BLE scanner is made using this library: https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx
And it was quite easy to work with and easy to understand.

This the code that made my app work:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, View, PermissionsAndroid, Text, Button, ScrollView, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {BleManager} from 'react-native-ble-plx';

export default class Ble_test extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.manager = new BleManager();
        this.state = {
            text1: '',
            components: [],
        };
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.manager.stopDeviceScan();
        this.manager.destroy();
        delete this.manager;
    }

    UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
        this.manager = new BleManager();
        if (Platform.OS === 'android' && Platform.Version >= 23) {
            PermissionsAndroid.check(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION).then((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    console.log('Permission is OK');
                } else {
                    PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION).then((result) => {
                        if (result === 'denied') {
                            console.log('User refuse');
                        } else {
                            console.log('User accept');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }

    async scanAndConnect() {
        this.manager.stopDeviceScan();

        this.setState({text1: 'Scanning...'});
        this.manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
            if (error) {
                alert('Error in scan=> ' + error);
                this.setState({text1: ''});
                this.manager.stopDeviceScan();
                this.UNSAFE_componentWillMount();
                return;
            }
            if (device.name != null) {
                let contains = false;

                for (const o of this.state.components) {
                    if (device.id === o.id) {
                        contains = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (contains === false) {
                    this.state.components.push(device);
                    this.setState({components: this.state.components});
                }
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Button block onPress={() => this.scanAndConnect()} title="Scan for a device">
                </Button>
                <View style={{alignItems: 'center', marginVertical: 10}}>
                    <Text>{this.state.text1}</Text>
                </View>
                <ScrollView>
                    {this.state.components.map((item, index) => (
                        <Text key={index} style={styles.welcome}>{
                            item.name
                        }
                        </Text>
                    ))}
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create(
    {
        welcome: {
            flex: 1,
            textAlign: 'center',
            textAlignVertical: 'center',
            backgroundColor: 'orange',
            marginTop: 10,
            height: 70,
        },
    },
);
```

In summary, is it possible to transfer data between two phones via Bluetooth using React Native? If yes, can I use BLE? or do I need Bluetooth Classic? And if possible can someone send me code snippets to help me on my way?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Thanks for your reply Michael Kotzjan! I have looked at the project for react-native-bluetooth-classic and I tried to run it but I can't figure out how. I just don't know how to make that project run. I am using a windows 10 pc and I want to run it on my android 7.1.1 device. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Hey, have you seen the [ReadMe](https://github.com/kenjdavidson/react-native-bluetooth-classic-apps/tree/main/BluetoothClassicExample#readme) from the example app? I believe it contains tips on how to start the app

Comment: Hey @MichaelKotzjan, this readMe is mostly how about how the app was created. After trying for a while I still have not figured out how to run/create it. It feels like I've tried almost everything, did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: I never actually tried it myself, I always expected it to work using `npx react-native start`, `react-native start` and `npx react-native run-android`. Refer to the React Native CLI Quickstart Tab in [this document](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

Comment: Not sure what's up, it should be as simple as running `npm android` within the project root.  I generally run the `BluetoothClassicExample` from Android studio (run/debug) both generally work.  Mainly use macos though, haven't tried to fire it up on windows.  If this is still an issue, feel free to open an issue on the project page and I can do my best to fire it up.

Comment: There are also a number of applications linked on the project page (usages) that perform this task.

Answer (score 2):

Communication between two phones using BLE is definitely possible. The reason you couldn't spot your second phone using your own BLE scanner is that BLE devices can only be found if they advertise their presence. Your second phone needs to act as a peripheral device and advertise a service for your first phone to connect to.

There are some free apps ([Ble Peripheral Simulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.github.webbluetoothcg.bletestperipheral&hl=de&gl=US), [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile), ...) that allow you to simulate a BLE peripheral using your phone which you can use to test this.

Unfortunately [react-native-ble-plx](https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx) clearly states

> It does NOT support:
>
> - bluetooth classic devices.
> - **communicating between phones using BLE (Peripheral support)**
> - bonding peripherals

The only library I found that might suit your purpose is [react-native-ble-peripheral](https://github.com/himelbrand/react-native-ble-peripheral) but it has not received an update for some time.

Regarding your problem using react-native-bluetooth-classic take a look at their [example app](https://github.com/kenjdavidson/react-native-bluetooth-classic-apps), maybe it helps you. Please refer to the [Read Me](https://github.com/kenjdavidson/react-native-bluetooth-classic-apps/tree/main/BluetoothClassicExample#readme) for instructions